# Why doesn't QCOMPARE return True in this case?

Tags: c++, qt, eigen

I'm writing tests for functions which are yet to be implemented. In the code below,even though the output and result vectors have the same value QCOMPARE returns False. Could someone explain why?

```
void EigenValuesTest::EigenValuesTestx2_data()
{
QTest::addColumn<Eigen::MatrixXd>("data");

Eigen::MatrixXd a(2,2);
a<<12,3,4,5;

QTest::newRow("0") << a ;
}

void EigenValuesTest::EigenValuesTestx2()
{
QFETCH(Eigen::MatrixXd, data);

Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXd> es(data,false);

Eigen::Vector2cd result;
result << std::complex<double>(13.4244,0),std::complex<double>(3.57557,0);

Eigen::Vector2cd output;
output = es.eigenvalues();

QCOMPARE(result,output);

}
```

Comment: How is `Eigen::Vector2cd::operator==` implemented?

Comment: @JeffreyvandeGlind I haven't been able to find any documentation on the ==. The Eigen tutorial seems to mention only arithmetic operators. However, if I declare two vectors of the same type and compare them using ==, it returns True.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
QCOMPARE(result.isApprox(output), true);
```

From the [Eigen documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a78f22189db1a4cc4634bb8427ae64f06),

```
bool operator== (const MatrixBase< OtherDerived > & other) const
```

> Returns true if each coefficients of *this and other are all *exactly*
>   equal. Warning **When using floating point** scalar values you probably
>   should rather **use a fuzzy comparison such as isApprox()** See Also
>   isApprox(), operator!=

**edit:** 
**Your eigen vectors are incorrect**. The zeros should be ones, ie `(13.4244, 1.0)`, `(3.57557, 1.0)`. Furthermore, they might appear in different order than the ones specified in the reference vector `result`. You need to take that in account for a more solid test.

Comment: In response to your edit: I am computing (complex)eigenvalues and not eigenvectors. Secondly, when I print result and output, I get the same thing so I don't think order is an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to quote from the documentation

> In the case of comparing floats and doubles, qFuzzyCompare() is used for comparing. This means that comparing to 0 will likely fail. One solution to this is to compare to 1, and add 1 to the produced output.

So far, so good. Done automatically, but now

> Note that comparing values where either p1 or p2 is 0.0 will not work. The solution to this is to compare against values greater than or equal to 1.0.

might result in a problem because you have zeros in your compared values.

Moreover I cannot say for sure, if `Q_COMPARE` works for the provided types. Any output may be helpful.

> QCOMPARE tries to output the contents of the values if the comparison fails, so it is visible from the test log why the comparison failed.

Comment: I don't think I can add 1 to the output since eigenvalues() returns a const value